# What is the problem with statistical outlier detection approaches if we have distribution of attributes?

Tags: distributions, dataset, outliers

A group of outlier discovery methods are statistical approaches. Two drawbacks mentioned for statistical methods in many books and papers:

1. They can apply just on a single attribute
2. We need to know our data distribution and distribution  parameters like standard deviation

**My question:** if we have distribution of all attributes, what is the problem? We can test each attribute separately and find outliers with respect to that. At the end, outliers detected for each attribute can gather as data-set outliers.

Is there any problem with this method?

Comment: What statistical detecton methods do you have in mind?

Comment: For a simple example, we know that our attributes have normal distribution, and we want to remove objects that aren't in the confidence area.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with that.

Comment: I think like you but many other approaches expressed it as a drawback for statistical methods. But seems this is not a drawback if we don't have 2th drawback. It means the only problem may be 2th drawback I mentioned above. Please guide me if I'm in mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your attributes can be correlated. Look at the following example:

[image: Example]

Note that the outlier marked in blue does not have unusual values in either x or y, it is the combination that makes it an outlier. Knowing the marginal distributions of each variable does not help, you need to know the full joint distribution.

Comment: +1 Very clear answer and illustration. In this case, a Mahalanobis distance might be helpful. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)